# Only send data from html form select is it is active

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a series of select parts of a form, the javascript hides multiple possibilities for the following dropdown until the current drop down has a selection made, this determines which dropdown the user sees using the `style="display:none;"` attribute and javascript to switch it to `block`, `.css({'display':'block'});`.

The problem is that each `<select>` segment has the same name, e.g. `<select class="form-control" name='phylum' id="sel1_1" style="display:none;">` this `name='phylum'` is used in the post phase of the form and needs to be associated with whichever dropdown list is used, but all of these have the default as `0` so if this is set it is overwritten by the final select in the list.

In javascript I therefore need to disable the html code, switching `display:none;` to `display:block;` has no effect as it is style only. Could I add `disabled` to all the `<select>` elements and somehow activate the required one?

Some example html and javascript snippets follow.

html

```
<div class='col-12 left'>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <label id="sel1_0" style="display:none;" for='uname'>Phylum/Division</label>
    <select class="form-control" name='phylum' id="sel1_1" style="display:none;">
      <option value="phylum" data-value="0">Choose</option>
      <option value="Annelid" data-value="1">Annelid</option>
      <option value="Arthropod" data-value="2">Arthropod</option>
      <option value="Bryozoa" data-value="3">Bryozoa</option>
      <option value="Chordata" data-value="4">Chordata</option>
      <option value="Cnidaria" data-value="5">Cnidaria</option>
      <option value="Echinoderm" data-value="6">Echinoderm</option>
      <option value="Mollusc" data-value="7">Mollusc</option>
      <option value="Nematode" data-value="8">Nematode</option>
      <option value="Platyhelminthes" data-value="9">Platyhelminthes</option>
      <option value="Rotifer" data-value="10">Rotifer</option>
      <option value="Sponge" data-value="11">Sponge</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" name='phylum' id="sel1_2" style="display:none;">
      <option value="0" data-value="0">Choose</option>
      <option value="1" data-value="1">C1</option>
      <option value="2" data-value="2">D1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$("#sel0").change(function() {
  $('#sel1_1').css({'display':'block'});
```

The following doesn't seem to work

```
  $('#sel1_1').css({'active'});
```

Comment: perhaps one way to achieve it is to add a listener to submit, prevent the default event, and then build the request with the selects you want and submit with ajax.

Comment: the other option would be to modify the DOM to remove those unused selects, but that would require something more complex like vuejs or other similar frameworks/libs

Comment: I'm trying to keep it simple, in theory only one snippet will have the data, the rest will have a value of zero `0` so is there anyway to say `if the value = 0, ignore`

Comment: How about setting `name=''` to all and in javascript is there anyway to change the text `name='' '` to `name='phylum'` in the select element?